# Naming guard clauses that throw exceptions

Tags: c#, design, object-oriented, refactoring, clean-code

I have a function `evaluate()` that parses a `String` for some variables and replaces them with their corresponding value:

```
public String evaluate() {
    String result = templateText;
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : variables.entrySet()) {
        String regex = "\\$\\{" + entry.getKey() + "\\}";
        result = result.replaceAll(regex, entry.getValue());
    }
    if (result.matches(".*\\$\\{.+\\}.*")) {    //<--check if a variable wasn't replaced
        throw new MissingValueException();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Since the `evaluate()` function now does 2 things, it first replaces the variables with the values **AND** check for any variables that weren't replaced, I thought about refactoring it to:

```
public String evaluate() {
    String result = templateText;
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : variables.entrySet()) {
        String regex = "\\$\\{" + entry.getKey() + "\\}";
        result = result.replaceAll(regex, entry.getValue());
    }
    checkForMissingValues(result);
}

private void checkForMissingValues(String result) {
    if (result.matches(".*\\$\\{.+\\}.*")) {
        throw new MissingValueException();
    }
}
```

Now is this a good name for the function `checkForMissingValues`? I mean it does check for missing values, but it also throws an exception.

I thought about renaming it to `throwExceptionIfMissingValueWasFound()`, but this name tells **HOW** the function does it more than **WHAT** the function is doing.

Is there a standard for naming such functions that check for a condition then throw an exception?

Comment: I don't like it.  It's not checking for missing values.  It's checkForMissedVariables!

Comment: The tag says C# but I see a Java-style for[each] being used as well as Java-style braces and Java-style method naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you call it `guardAgainstMissingValues()` it's simple and conveys the message directly.

Just ask yourself what does this function do? It **guards** against Missing values. You said it yourself that it's a guard clause, so why don't you name it accordingly.

In addition I think that the term guard clause implies a check in its implementation, so you won't have to explicitly mention the check in the function's name.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `ensureThisOrThatAttribute`, which, in combination with an explicit `throws CustomMadeException` declaration makes things clear enough.

However, more important than conforming to some alleged general standard is that you conform to **your own** code base's standard. If you don't have one yet, well, just pick a format now and stick with it.

Comment: A small addition that might be helpful: `pick a format now, document it, and stick with it`

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer a convention such as this:

```
static class Guard {
  public static void IsNotNull(value) {
    if(value == null) {
      throw new MyCustomGuardException();
    }
  }
}
```

Later on when using it:

```
public function DoSomething(DateTime startedAt) {
  Guard.IsNotNull(startedAt);
}
```

A more complete example of a fluent guard class can be found in the NetFX package here:

http://netfx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/89b72bee718c#Extensions/System/Guard/Source/content/netfx/System/Guard.cs

Comment: As a side thought, I would expect a method called `IsNotNull` to return a boolean and never except.

Comment: I would as well; however, this method is static and will be written "Guard.IsNotNull" and I would expect a method called "GuardIsNotNull" to throw an exception.

Comment: You still have a method that is a boolean condition. It either is or it isn't. Throwing an exception when the true return is false doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. I'd love to see your answer to the question with the conventions you find to work the best.

Comment: It's a naming convention, not rocket science. `IsNotNull` should return true/false. If a convention provides for an exception, the method name should leave room for that. `Guard.ValidateNotNull` would be my recommendation in the case of your example. That indicates an action, and that action has the possibility of exception. 'IsNotNull` is still a boolean and should still return a boolean. Even the link you provided I would say names things in a confusing manner. Consider `String.IsNullOrEmpty` as an example.

Comment: As for my answer, I have already up-voted the answer I consider most helpful.

Comment: @JoelEtherton NUnit uses `Assert.IsNotNull` (`Asert.AreEqual` etc.) and they do throw exceptions. Just a case in point. Personally I see nothing wrong with it - in this particular context. That's because the name of the class is used as a verb. `Assert.AssertAreEqual` etc. (the original, JUnit convention I think?) would appear redundant to me.

Comment: @KonradMorawski: I can see that, but I would also argue that the name of the class does not represent an object (which would be an assertion), and because of that violates a similar naming convention for objects.

Comment: I use `Argument.ThrowIfNull(...)` which is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Your routine name seems perfectly fine to me. What's so bad about "check"?

I tend to break it up, though. So I have a routine that does the check/throw, plus functions that do the actual tests. You'd wind up with something like:

```
check(!hasMissingValues(result));
```

This makes it more than just a naming convention. You can call it "validate" or "enforce" or whatever, but the key it that `check` has a defined behavior.

(This of course assumes that the kinds of conditions you're `check`ing don't need a bunch of custom exception info, but that is often the case.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this warrants a separate method.
I also noticed several things:

You create a `Pattern` object for each variable in your `Map`. Pattern object creation is expensive (requires parsing). You then evaluate the regex on the string with `replaceAll`. So if you have 100 variables that becomes 100 regexes parsed and created then string is scanned 100 times. That's inefficient.

Your regex to scan for missing variables is exceedingly expensive. It will scan each character in your string many many many times, especially if it contains `${`.

What you need to do is flip the logic. Find strings `${x}` in text and retrieve variables from your map to fill that, throwing an exception the first time you encounter a missing variable.

```
public String evaluate() {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\.+?\\)}").matcher(templateText);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(templateText.length());
    while(matcher.find()) {
        String val = variables.get(matcher.group(1));
        if (val == null) throw new MissingValueException();
        matcher.appendReplacement(result, val);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(result);
    return result.toString();
}
```

This will search the string only once with only a single regex. It will fail on first missing variable. If you have 100 variables defined but only 1 appears in the template only 1 replace is done.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, methods in C# follow the Pascal convention, so it should be Evaluate  and not evaluate.

Second: It is natural for methods to throw exceptions in, well, exceptional scenarios so you DONT have to name your method to signify this.

Third: It is not normal to throw an exception due to an internal check (unless you have a specific need). Ideally the method should return a bool which states whether the check succeeded or failed. So the method signature should ideally be:

```
private bool IsMissingValues(String result)
```

Next, a method name does not always have to explain every single detail of what it does, always read it in conjunction with the class in which it is defined.

Hence, `String.Replace` is sufficient; `String.ReplaceThisStringWithAnother` is overkill.

Speaking of which, your evaluate method should ideally be called Replace or something as that it what it essentially does.

Also private methods can be relatively less 'wordy' than public ones since no one else except you will see it (ok fine, that's debatable).

Answer (score 0):

```
public String evaluate() {
    String result = replaceVariablesWithValues();
       // Extract the for loop code to the new method listed above

    if (resultContainsVariables(result)) {    
         // All variables should have been replaced
        throw new MissingValueException();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Above is my proposal for how to refactor.

1. The proposed evaluate function describes succinctly both the general functionality (replace variables with values) as well as the exception case (if the result contains variables, throw an exception).
2. The details of the regex evaluations should be extracted to helper functions because one should not need to mentally parse the regex to understand the contract and control flow of evaluate. Also, I suggest making the regex prefix and suffix constants.
3. I suggest keeping the throw statement in evaluate. It is not obvious what a "check" or guard function does, but knowing what such a function does is required to understand the contract of evaluate.